# Вызов функции из другого модуля

Tags: python, функции

Есть задача:
Имеется функция incrimentGlobalVar для теста прописал, что раз в 3 секунды добавляется счетчик +1.
Мне нужно подучить значение этого счетчика, вызвав функцию из соседнего модуля (постараться без глобальных переременных)

```
import time

def incrimentGlobalVar():

    incrimentGlobalVar._someVar = incrimentGlobalVar._someVar + 1 if hasattr(incrimentGlobalVar, "_someVar") else 0
    return incrimentGlobalVar._someVar

def loop():
    while True:
        incrimentGlobalVar()
        print(incrimentGlobalVar._someVar)
        time.sleep(3)
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop()
```

Сосдедний модуль выглядит так:

```
import func
print(func.incrimentGlobalVar())
print(func.incrimentGlobalVar())   
print(func.incrimentGlobalVar())
```

Результат, из модулья я получаю не текущие значения счетчика 0, 1, 2, те запускаеться какая-то копия или поток этой функции. Как подключиться именно к том, что сейчас происходит внутри функции incrimentGlobalVar():?

Пробовал похожее сделать на классах, результат тот же.

```
import time
class FuncCreator:
    def __init__(self, T1):
        self.state = T1

    def __call__(self):
        print(self.state)
        self.state += 1

func6 = FuncCreator(100)

def fff():
    func6()

def loop():
    while True:
        func6()
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop()
```

Вызывл так:

```
import func
print(func.fff())
print(func.fff())   
print(func.fff())
```

Comment: мне кажется, решение найдется тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861164/passing-data-between-separately-running-python-scripts

Comment: Если у вас запущены два разных процесса, то вы не можете получить в одном процессе данные другого процесса просто запустив ещё один такой же код как в том процессе. Эти данные нужно как-то передать. Через файл, через сеть, через БД, через специальные какие-то объекты ОС, но передать как-то надо будет.